# BlockingCollection<T> throws unexpected InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, producer-consumer, .net-8.0, blockingcollection

I was trying out `BlockingCollection<T>` (as a Queue) in .NET8 and sometimes I end up with the exception:

"**System.InvalidOperationException: The collection argument is empty and has been marked as complete with regards to additions.**"

Code example:

```
    private static void TestMethod()
    {
        using BlockingCollection<DummyClass> queue = new BlockingCollection<DummyClass>();

        var task = Task.Run(() =>  //Produce
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                queue.Add(new DummyClass());
            }
            queue.CompleteAdding();

        });

        int counter = 0;
        try
        {
            while (!queue.IsCompleted)  //Consume
            {
                DummyClass item = queue.Take(); // <-- Sometimes exception here
                counter++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"counter={counter} ");
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

IsCompleted states "Whether this collection has been marked as complete for adding **and is empty**."

So as long as CompleteAdding() has not been called Take() should be blocking and when CompleteAdding() has been called and the queue is empty, " !queue.IsCompleted " should return false.

What am I missing?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Running in VS2022 17.8.5 on Windows 11.

Comment: It is working on dotnet fiddle. You can check here https://dotnetfiddle.net/dhvDxG

Comment: Nothing guarantees that the queue is still active between `IsCompleted` and `Take()`. The [documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) uses a `catch(InvalidOperationException){}`. What are you trying to do though? There are better, truly asynchronous (ie non-blocking) collections for producer/consumer scenarios, like Channel<T>

Comment: @Sandy it's not really working except by accident.

Comment: To avoid the exception use [TryTake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.trytake?view=net-8.0). It's better to use Channel though. You could write `await foreach(var item in channelReader.ReadAllAsync()){ counter++});` without ever blocking to wait for data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I originally used the queue.GetConsumingEnumerable() in a foreach(), but I’m having some crazy performance requirements and found a lot of questions regarding performance when using the Enumerator. Using Take() directly was just an idea (that didn’t pay off). However, I found this nice idea (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039724/blockingcollectiont-performance/53995723#53995723) that actually made just my queue handling 3-4 times faster :-)  Thanks for your input!

Comment: That's still too slow and complicated compared to Channel. As for enumerator performance, do you have a *real, measurable* problem? The real delays come from waiting, not enumerators. What you read may not even apply any more. .NET Core introduced optimizations that resulted in orders of magnitude better performance compared to .NET Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a thread race; imagine:

- the queue is empty
- thread A is about to call `queue.CompleteAdding();`
- thread B is about to check  `while (!queue.IsCompleted)`
- thread B gets some cycles, finds it is not currently completed
- thread A gets some cycles, marks the queue as complete
- thread B gets some cycles, calls `Take()`

and boom

Solution: use `TryTake`

Comment: Or a more suitable collection like Channel

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense :-)
Is there a ”correct” way to use Take()? I’m not so found of Microsofts example on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-8.0) as it uses exception for the “normal” behavior.
```
try
{
    // Consume the BlockingCollection
    while (true) Console.WriteLine(bc.Take());
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    // An InvalidOperationException means that Take() was called on a completed collection
    Console.WriteLine("That's All!");
}
```

Comment: @Steve honestly, I simply wouldn't these days; @Panagiotis is entirely correct that `Channel<T>` is a better API for this scenario, essentially acting as an asynchronous pipe

Comment: Marc the `Channel<T>` is for asynchronous scenarios. When both the producer and the consumer are synchronous, the `BlockingCollection<T>` is preferable. The `Channel<T>` doesn't have synchronous APIs, and doing sync-over-async has non-negligible overhead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias why use *synchronous* code in a producer/consumer scenario where each part runs on a separate thread? That just burns electricity due to spinwaiting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the purpose of asynchronous programming is to make efficient use of threads, not to lower the energy bill. Using one dedicated thread for the producer and another thread for the consumer is perfectly fine. If you go async, the `ThreadPool` will create at least two threads anyway, and on top of that you'll get the [scheduling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channeloptions.allowsynchronouscontinuations) penalty on all truly async operations on the channel.

Comment: If you had a high traffic server farm you wouldn't say that even as a joke, because the cost is counted in *servers* not percentages. In a high traffic deployment blocking means spiwaits which means cores pegged at 100% which means IIS app pool recycles, which means the load balancers redirect traffic to other servers, which means you get cascading failures until the eventual site crash.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos are you assuming that the OP intends to run producer-consumer pairs on a web server, launching one pair per web request? This would be an atypical use of the producer-consumer pattern, and there is no indication in the question that the OP has this intention. If that's the case then, yes, going async would be highly advisable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias IMO the channel API is relevant and preferable regardless of whether you're running in a server environment

Comment: Marc why? Because of a general preference for asynchronous programming? I doubt that you've seen any benchmarks that favor the one over the other, or that you find the shape of the API more intuitive than the other.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I didn't mention performance; simply: the API shape is just better for this producer/consumer scenario, aptly demonstrated by how easily OP was led into a bad path here.

Comment: OK Marc, thanks for clarifying that your preference is not driven by experimentally obtained performance metrics. I don't agree that the shape of the API is confusing per se. Personally I prefer the simplicity of the `BlockingCollection<T>` over the `Reader`/`Writer` shenanigans of the `Channel<T>`. I would agree though that a lack of examples in the documentation (as with the `Channel<T>`) is preferable to outdated examples that demonstrate bad patterns (as of the `BlockingCollection<T>`).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to consume a `BlockingCollection<T>` is the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) method:

```
foreach (DummyClass item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // Process the consumed item
}
```

Unfortunately this handy method is not featured prominently enough in Microsoft's documentation and examples. Personally I never had a need for either the `IsCompleted` or `Take` members of the collection. Here is how it is [implemented internally](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs#L1612):

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (IsCompleted)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    using CancellationTokenSource linkedTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _consumersCancellationTokenSource.Token);
    while (TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation(out T? item, Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken, linkedTokenSource))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```